# Converting SVG to ICO with transparent background

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I am attempting to use ImageMagick to do a batch conversion of svg files to ico.  However, the command I'm currently using is not retaining the background transparency of the svgs.

```
mogrify -background transparent -format ico -density 600 -define icon:auto-resize=128,64,48,32,16 *.svg
```

Here is the code for one of the SVGs (exported using the application Sketch):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 41.2 (35397) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>Add</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <polygon id="path-1" points="0 40 40 40 40 0 0 0"></polygon>
    </defs>
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <g transform="translate(20.000000, 20.000000) scale(1, -1) translate(-20.000000, -20.000000) ">
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                                    <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                                </mask>
                                <g></g>
                                <g mask="url(#mask-2)">
                                    <g transform="translate(-0.250000, 1.250000)">
                                        <g stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="translate(0.075125, 8.043250)">
                                            <path d="M1.5,3.75 C0.765,3.75 0.175,3.06625 0.175,2.20875 C0.175,1.345 0.765,0.64875 1.5,0.64875 L12.49,0.64875 C13.22125,0.64875 13.825,1.345 13.825,2.20875 C13.825,3.06625 13.22125,3.75 12.49,3.75" fill="#8C8C8C"></path>
                                        </g>
                                        <g stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="translate(0.058000, 24.804125)">
                                            <path d="M1.5,3.75 C0.775,3.75 0.1925,3.06625 0.1925,2.20875 C0.1925,1.345 0.775,0.64875 1.5,0.64875 L12.84125,0.64875 C13.56375,0.64875 12.88625,1.43125 12.88625,2.29375 C12.88625,3.1525 13.56375,3.75 12.84125,3.75" fill="#8C8C8C"></path>
                                        </g>
                                        <g stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="translate(29.431125, 16.666875)">
                                            <path d="M1.5,3.75 C0.765,3.75 0.175,3.06625 0.175,2.20875 C0.175,1.345 0.765,0.6475 1.5,0.6475 L9.43375,0.6475 C10.16625,0.6475 10.76875,1.345 10.76875,2.20875 C10.76875,3.06625 10.16625,3.75 9.43375,3.75" fill="#444443"></path>
                                        </g>
                                        <g stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="translate(12.898875, 0.017750)">
                                            <path d="M0,37.5 L0,0 C0,0 17.37,1.91625 17.37,17.925 C17.37,35.7 3.3325,37.5 0,37.5 Z" stroke="#8C8C8C" stroke-width="2.5"></path>
                                        </g>
                                        <polygon fill="#3C3C3C" points="40.25 8.68375 14.13625 8.68375 14.13625 28.5525 40.25 28.5525 40.25 8.68375"></polygon>
                                        <g stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="translate(18.442125, 16.451375)">
                                            <path d="M2.5,3.75 C1.62375,3.75 0.9175,3.04875 0.9175,2.17375 C0.9175,1.2975 1.62375,0.58375 2.5,0.58375 L14.92375,0.58375 C15.7975,0.58375 16.52125,1.2975 16.52125,2.17375 C16.52125,3.04875 15.7975,3.75 14.92375,3.75" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                                        </g>
                                        <g stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="translate(25.577125, 9.899875)">
                                            <path d="M0,2.5 C0,1.62125 0.70125,0.91625 1.5775,0.91625 C2.45125,0.91625 3.1675,1.62125 3.1675,2.5 L3.1675,14.9225 C3.1675,15.7975 2.45125,16.52 1.5775,16.52 C0.70125,16.52 0,15.7975 0,14.9225" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                                        </g>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The resulting ico has a black background:

[image]

How can I maintain the transparency of the icon background?

Comment: remove the mask perhaps?

Comment: @RobertLongson interesting idea, but it unfortunately still produced a black background

Comment: It works fine on my version - are you using the `svg` or the (preferable) `rsvg` delegate?

Comment: @MarkSetchell can you explain what you mean by this?  I am using ImageMagick 6.9.6-6 Q16 x86_64 2017-01-03

Comment: Try `identify -list delegate | grep svg` and see if you are using `rsvg` to interpret SVG files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it looks like that's the case: "svg =>          "rsvg-convert' -o '%o' '%i""

Comment: Mmmm, looks ok - not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: @MarkSetchell what OS are you using, and what version of ImageMagick?

Answer (score 22):

This does the trick for me:

```
convert -background transparent -define 'icon:auto-resize=16,24,32,64' logo.svg favicon.ico
```

It automatically resizes the SVG to four sizes, retaining transparency.

Comment: Are these parameters order-dependent? I tried  `convert logo.svg -background transparent -define 'icon:auto-resize=16,24,32,64' favicon.ico` and it did not worked. Bug or order-dependent?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `-transparent` option to set color which will be used as a transparency channel, which in case of *.svg is "white".

See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#transparent

For example to convert *.svg to *.ico with transparency preserved use:

```
-transparent white -format ico -resize 64x64
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me using ImageMagick 6.9.9.27 Q16 Mac OSX and RSVG delegate for rendering SVG at version RSVG 2.40.18.

```
convert -background none test.svg test.png
```

You probably need to install the RSVG delegate or Inkscape, since the IM internal MSVG/XML renderer is not that good. You can check what renderer you have using

```
convert -list format
```

And look at the line for SVG. Mine shows

```
SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.18)
```

What is your IM version and what SVG renderer are you using. Perhaps you just need to upgrade RSVG if you have it installed and ImageMagick can find it.

ImageMagick will use Inkscape (the best one to use) if it is installed in your system. Otherwise, it will use RSVG if you have that installed as a delegate. Otherwise if neither exist is uses it's own internal renderer, which is not that good.

If this works for you, then you can proceed to create ico files.

Mogrify also works for me with the same system configuration:

```
mogrify -format ico -background none -density 600 -define icon:auto-resize=128,64,48,32,16 test.svg 

identify test.ico
test.ico[0] ICO 128x128 128x128+0+0 8-bit sRGB 99678B 0.000u 0:00.000
test.ico[1] ICO 64x64 64x64+0+0 8-bit sRGB 99678B 0.000u 0:00.000
test.ico[2] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 8-bit sRGB 99678B 0.000u 0:00.000
test.ico[3] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 8-bit sRGB 99678B 0.000u 0:00.000
test.ico[4] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 8-bit sRGB 99678B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Where identify -verbose shows that each level has transparency.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the alpha argument of mogrify see [image magick's doc](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#alpha)

You should add "-alpha set" and it should work.

Comment: Using "-alpha transparent" produces .ico files that are completely white.  This is the command I used: mogrify -format ico -density 600 -alpha transparent -define icon:auto-resize=128,64,48,32,16 *.svg

Comment: Try with "set" instead of transparent

Comment: with "set" I am still getting .icos with black backgrounds: mogrify -format ico -density 600 -alpha set -define icon:auto-resize=128,64,48,32,16 *.svg

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: Do a command "identify -list color" and copy/paste the output

Comment: ok - it produced quite along list. is there something in particular you're looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132231/discussion-between-tofandel-and-scientiffic).

Comment: Please identify your platform and version of ImageMagick. Use `convert -version` if on IM 6 and `magick -version` if on IM 7. Also do `convert -list format` and look at the line for SVG. At the end of that line it will tell you in parentheses what delegate is being used to render the SVG file. It could be RSVG or XML/MSVG or Inkscape. Let us know which one it is and the version. Perhaps you need to upgrade the version or use a better renderer. The IM internal renderer MSVG/XML is not so good. Better is RSVG and best is Inkscape if you put that on your system, it will be used.